# Reading an XML in HTML client side?

Tags: html, xml

Is there a way to read an XML file via HTML/Javascript on the client side?

I know I can add the XML data in the string in the javascript of the page. This solution works but it would be great if the xml file could be added like a css or a javascript file.

**Is there a way to add a XML file like you would add a js file?**

Comment: Can I ask why you would need to include an XML file in a HTML page? XML files don't 'do' anything on their own.

Comment: The data as over 600 lines and is generated on the fly. The javascript is doing the rendering.

Comment: I don't think you can include it like a CSS or JS file. If the JS is rendering it, then surely you would need to include it in the JS file, like you said? I don't really know a lot about using XML on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could convert the XML into JSON or import it into a database first.

PHP has a library called Simple XML Parser that comes with most distributions. The interface is really straightforward.

Python also has a rich library called lxml to parse XML.

As the comments noted, accessing an XML file on the fly is probably not efficient.